# ColdFusion 10.0 ORMSearch returns two separate queries: entity + score - Bug 3338790

Tags: search, coldfusion, entity, coldfusion-10

I was perhaps wondering if anyone out there had a solution to ColdFusion 10.0  -  [Bug 3338790](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3338790). Which, in short, causes ORMSearch to return an Array with two structures: entity and score. I cannot figure out how to combine these two arrays either with CFML or AS3 -- I've tried append, loops, etc.

I'd greatly appreciate any help you may provide. Thank you.

AK

Comment: Did you notice the NOTE that was added by the OP of that bug?  Looks like they were using an incorrect offset.  Could you provide examples of your query, the output you are receiving and the output that you want?